# Get values from product1, product2... etc with loop in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am new to VBA, but well, I think what I want it can be done for sure.

I have a table with different clients and every client has it own ID.

In the table, every client buys different number of products.
For example, the client with ID = 3 buys 3 products.
In the table I name them product1, product2, product3.

```
Dim intTotal, totalCompra As Double
Dim wApp As Word.Application
Dim wDoc As Word.Document
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim cantidad As Integer
Dim intCantidad As Integer
Dim intPrecio As Double

Set wApp = New Word.Application
Set wDoc = wApp.Documents.Open("C:\...\factura_alcazaba.docx")
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select * FROM Ventas_Alcazaba WHERE ID =" & idInt & ";")

wDoc.Bookmarks("Name").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Nombre_cliente, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("NIF").Range.Text = Nz(rs!NIF, "")
wDoc.Bookmarks("Fecha").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Fecha, "")
cantidad = Nz(rs!Numero_productos, "")

If Not IsEmpty(rs!Cantidad_prod1) Then
    intCantidad = rs!Cantidad_prod1
    wDoc.Bookmarks("cantidad1").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Cantidad_prod1, "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks("descripcion1").Range.Text = Nz(rs!Descripcion_prod1, "")
    intPrecio = rs!Precio_prod1
    intTotal = intPrecio * intCantidad
    totalCompra = totalCompra + intTotal
    wDoc.Bookmarks("precio1").Range.Text = Nz(intPrecio, "")
    wDoc.Bookmarks("prod1_total").Range.Text = Nz(intTotal, "")
End If

'For i = 1 To cantidad
    'intCantidad = rs!Cantidad_prod + i
    'wDoc.Bookmarks("cantidad" + i).Range.Text = Nz(rs!["Cantidad_prod" & i], "")
   ' wDoc.Bookmarks("descripcion" & i).Range.Text = Nz(rs!["Descripcion_prod" + i], "")
   ' intPrecio = Nz(rs!["Precio_prod" & i], "")
    'intTotal = intPrecio * intCantidad
   ' totalCompra = totalCompra + intTotal
   ' wDoc.Bookmarks("precio1").Range.Text = Nz(intPrecio, "")
   ' wDoc.Bookmarks("prod1_total").Range.Text = Nz(intTotal, "")
'Next i
wDoc.SaveAs2 "C:\Factura_" & rs!ID & ".docx"

wDoc.Close False
wApp.Quit
```

Using the If I can get every value if exist in the table. But it is very inefficient and I would like to do it with a loop.
But I don't know how to call the different products only change the final number.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with string concatenation like this:

```
intCantidad = rs("Cantidad_prod" & i)
```

like you did here:

```
wDoc.Bookmarks("descripcion" & i)
```

**But** it should be noted that this seems like bad table design. What if a client buys 5 products? Or 10?

Products (or rather Sales) should be a separate table with a foreign key to clients.

Comment: Uhmmm, I know, it is because I want something simple. It is a favour for my brother.
I will add like maximum ten products because my brother is not the seller. He only makes the bills for another business so if he needs more products, he can add them himself.
I only make this because he usually uses excel hehe.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is: you don't make it simple, you make it harder for yourself. And him. The table structures for Clients - Products - Orders - Order Positions are in just about any database example, including the Northwind sample database (I think). It *does* pay of to do it right the first time.

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem was that I didn't know that access was so nice. I am gonna create the tables Products, Clients, Sales and the pertinent tables with the key IDs. It would be a little more time but it will be better.